# R portfolio analytics chart.EfficientFrontier function

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, portfolio

I am trying to use the chart.EfficientFrontier function in the portfolioanalytics package in R to chart an efficient frontier object that I have created but it keeps failing. Basically I am trying to find a frontier that will minimize **annaulized** standard deviation. Eventually once I get this working I would also like to maximize **annualized** return.

Firstly I created an annualized standard deviation function using this code

```
pasd <- function(R, weights){
  as.numeric(StdDev(R=R, weights=weights)*sqrt(12)) # hardcoded for monthly data
  # as.numeric(StdDev(R=R, weights=weights)*sqrt(4)) # hardcoded for quarterly data
}
```

I imported a csv file with monthly returns and my portfolio object looks like this:

```
> prt
**************************************************
PortfolioAnalytics Portfolio Specification 
**************************************************

Call:
portfolio.spec(assets = colnames(returns))

Number of assets: 3 
Asset Names
[1] "Global REITs"      "Au REITs"          "Au Util and Infra"

Constraints
Enabled constraint types
        - leverage 
        - long_only 

Objectives:
Enabled objective names
        - mean 
        - pasd
```

Now I successfully create an efficient frontier object using this line:

```
prt.ef <- create.EfficientFrontier(R = returns, portfolio = prt, type = "DEoptim", match.col = "pasd")
```

But when I try to plot it I am getting the following error messages.

```
> chart.EfficientFrontier(prt.ef, match.col="pasd")
Error in StdDev(R = R, weights = weights) : 
  argument "weights" is missing, with no default
In addition: There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Error in StdDev(R = R, weights = weights) : 
  argument "weights" is missing, with no default
Error in StdDev(R = R, weights = weights) : 
  argument "weights" is missing, with no default
Error in xlim[2] * 1.15 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Anyone know why this is the case? When I use summary(prt.ef) I can see the weights, but why is the chart.EfficientFrontier function failing?

Comment: `chart.EfficientFrontier` expects to be able to call `pasd` without weights to compute sigmas for each asset and with weights to compute the portfolio sigma.  To eliminate the error message, make `pasd` work like `StdDev` by using  `pasd <- function(R, weights=NULL)  as.numeric(StdDev(R=R, weights=weights)*sqrt(12))` .         Also, to do a consistent analysis, you should annualize returns but then the optimization will calculate the same weights for monthly and annualized portfolios.

Comment: I changed the `pasd` function like how you suggested but the chart.EfficientFrontier still gives me errors.   `chart.EfficientFrontier(prt.ef, match.col="pasd")
Error in StdDev(R = R, weights = weights) : object 'NuLL' not found
Error in StdDev(R = R, weights = weights) : object 'NuLL' not found
Error in StdDev(R = R, weights = weights) : object 'NuLL' not found
Error in xlim[2] * 1.15 : non-numeric argument to binary operator `

Answer (score 2):

As @WaltS suggested, you need to be consistent in implementing functions to annualize mean and risk returns.

But actually to get annualized statistics you have two options, you are not using any:

1) Make the optimization with monthly data, with the original risk return functions in the specification. For plotting you can anualize making

```
Port.Anua.Returns=prt.ef$frontier[,1]*12 
Port.Anua.StDev=prt.ef$frontier[,2]*12^.5
```

The weights will be the same for monthly or annualized portfolios.

```
prt.ef$frontier[,-(1:3)]
```

2) Transform your monthly returns in annualized returns multiplying by 12. Then do the optimization with the usual procedure, all risk and return will be already annualized in `prt.ef$frontier`.

Related to the jagged line in EF. Using your portfolio specification I was also able to recreate the same behavior. For the following plot I used `edhec` data, your specification with original `mean` and `StdDev` in the objectives:

```
data(edhec)
returns <- edhec[,1:3]
```

[image]

That behavior must be influenced by the specification or the optimization algorithm you are using. I did the same optimization with `solve.QP` from package  `quadprog`. This is the result.
[image]

Update

The code is here:

```
require(quadprog) 
#min_x(-d^T x + 1/2 b^T D x) r.t A.x>=b
MV_QP<-function(nx, tarRet, Sig=NULL,long_only=FALSE){
  if (is.null(Sig)) Sig=cov(nx)
  dvec=rep(0,ncol(Sig))
  meq=2
  Amat=rbind(rep(1,ncol(Sig)),
             apply(nx,2,mean) )
  bvec=c(1,tarRet )
  if (long_only) {
    meq=1
    Amat=Amat[-1,]
    Amat=rbind(Amat,
               diag(1,ncol(Sig)),
               rep(1,ncol(Sig)),
               rep(-1,ncol(Sig)))
    bvec=bvec[-1]
    bvec=c(bvec,
               rep(0,ncol(Sig)),.98,-1.02)
  }
  sol  <- solve.QP(Dmat=Sig, dvec, t(Amat), bvec, meq=meq)$solution 
}

steps=50
x=returns
 µ.b <- apply(X = x, 2, FUN = mean) 
long_only=TRUE
range.bl <- seq(from = min(µ.b), to = max(µ.b)*ifelse(long_only,1,1.6), length.out = steps) 
risk.bl <- t(sapply(range.bl, function(targetReturn) { 
  w <- MV_QP(x, targetReturn,long_only=long_only) 
  c(sd(x %*% w),w)  }))

weigthsl=round(risk.bl[,-1],4)
colnames(weigthsl)=colnames(x)
weigthsl
risk.bl=risk.bl[,1]
rets.bl= weigthsl%*%µ.b
fan=12
plot(x = risk.bl*fan^.5, y = rets.bl*fan,col=2,pch=21,
     xlab = "Annualized Risk ", 
     ylab = "Annualized Return", main = "long only EF with solve.QP")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that but what I don't understand is annualizing the monthly returns by multiplying them by 12. I am already importing a monthly returns series and I would have an annualized return there by chain linking each monthly return (1+r1)*(1+r2)*(1+r3).....(1+r12) - 1

Comment: Also can you please post the code for the optimization using `solve.QP`?

Comment: I understood you want the equivalent annualized return and annual standard deviation from monthly EF data, for that you just include the scale=12. In this case you are supposed to invest each month. A different history is to transform the problem to make the investments every year, for that you will need a long series of annual returns, in that case yes you can compound the monthly returns.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Robert's comments,   the optimization calculation with monthly returns is a quadratic programming problem with linear constraints.  When `mean` is the `return` objective and `StdDev` or `var` is the `risk` objective, `optimize.portfolio` and `create.EfficientFrontier` select the `ROI` method as the solver which uses `solve.QP`, an efficient solver for these sorts of problems.  When the `risk` objective is changed to `pasd`, these functions don't recognize this as a QP problem so use `DEoptim` a general nonlinear problem solver perhaps better suited to solving nonconvex problem rather than convex QP ones. See  [Differential Evolution with DEoptim](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Ardia~et~al.pdf) .  This seems to be the cause of the jagged efficient frontier.

In order to have `create.EfficientFrontier` use `solve.QP`, which is much more efficient and accurate for this type of problem, you can make a custom moment function to compute the mean and variance and then specify it with the argument `momentFUN`.   However, `create.EfficientFrontier` at least in part uses means computed directly from the returns rather than using `mu` from `momentFUN`.  To deal with that, multiply the returns and divide the variance by 12 as shown in the example below.

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
  data(edhec)
  returns <- edhec[,1:3]
#  define moment function
  annualized.moments <- function(R, scale=12, portfolio=NULL){
    out <- list()
    out$mu <-    matrix(colMeans(R), ncol=1)
    out$sigma <- cov(R)/scale
    return(out)
  }
# define portfolio
  prt <- portfolio.spec(assets=colnames(returns))
  prt <- add.constraint(portfolio=prt, type="long_only")
  #  leverage defaults to weight_sum = 1 so is equivalent to full_investment constraint
  prt <- add.constraint(portfolio=prt, type="leverage")
  prt <- add.objective(portfolio=prt, type="risk", name="StdDev")
# calculate and plot efficient frontier
  prt_ef <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=12*returns, portfolio=prt, type="mean-StdDev", 
                                      match.col = "StdDev", momentFUN="annualized.moments", scale=12)
  xlim <- range(prt_ef$frontier[,2])*c(1, 1.5)
  ylim <- range(prt_ef$frontier[,1])*c(.80, 1.05)
  chart.EfficientFrontier(prt_ef, match.col="StdDev", chart.assets = FALSE, 
                          labels.assets = FALSE, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim )
  points(with(annualized.moments(12*returns, scale=12), cbind(sqrt(diag(sigma)), mu)), pch=19 ) 
  text(with(annualized.moments(12*returns, scale=12), cbind(sqrt(diag(sigma)), mu)), 
       labels=colnames(returns), cex=.8, pos=4) 
  chart.EF.Weights(prt_ef, match.col="StdDev")
```

The means and standard deviations of the assets also need to be adjusted and so are plotted outside of `chart.EfficientFrontier` and shown on the chart below.

[image]

At the end of the day it would be simpler, as Robert suggests, to compute the weights for the efficient frontier using the monthly returns and then compute the portfolio returns and standard deviations using annualized asset means and standard deviations and the monthly weights which are the same in both cases.  However,  perhaps this example is useful to show the use of custom moment and objective functions.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I've only just started using R and it is taking me ages to do stuff in it. For now I've resorted to doing this in excel, but it will be good to look back on this and try to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Does not find the reason of the error, but setting the limits it partially works!

```
prt.ef$frontier  #see the EF
xylims=apply(prt.ef$frontier[,c(2,1)],2,range)*c(.98,1.01)
chart.EfficientFrontier(prt.ef, match.col="pasd", 
      main="Portfolio Optimization", 
      xlim=xylims[,1], ylim=xylims[,2])
#or
plot(prt.ef$frontier[,c(2,1)],col=2)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the limits do? For some reason the frontier I am seeing is a jagged line, not a smooth curve.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I tried the `pasd` function that WaltS suggested, and the chart.EfficientFrontier seemed to work but it gave me a jagged line and not a smooth line.

I have now created an annualized return function using this code:

```
pamean <- function(R, weights=NULL){Return.annualized(apply(as.xts(t(t(R) * weights)),1,sum))}
```

and added this as an objective to my portfolio prt.

```
> prt
**************************************************
PortfolioAnalytics Portfolio Specification 
**************************************************

Call:
portfolio.spec(assets = colnames(returns))

Number of assets: 3 
Asset Names
[1] "Global REITs"      "Au REITs"          "Au Util and Infra"

Constraints
Enabled constraint types
        - long_only 
        - leverage 

Objectives:
Enabled objective names
        - pamean 
        - pasd
```

I then create the efficient frontier again using this line:

```
> prt.ef <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=returns, portfolio=prt, type="DEoptim", match.col="pasd")
```

but when I use the summary function I see that only 1 frontier point has been generated. What does the error msg mean and why was only 1 point generated?

```
> summary(prt.ef)
**************************************************
PortfolioAnalytics Efficient Frontier 
**************************************************

Call:
create.EfficientFrontier(R = returns, portfolio = prt, type = "DEoptim", 
    match.col = "pasd")

Efficient Frontier Points: 1 

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = character(0)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```