# PortfolioAnalytics Error with function gmv_opt

Tags: r, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I have below script which creates an error. Does anyone know how to solve this. I'm running the latest version of R & RStudio, and all packages are up to date.

```
library('quantmod')
library('PortfolioAnalytics')
library('PerformanceAnalytics')

ETF_Names     <- c("IVV","IJH","IWM","EZU","EEM","SCZ","ILF","EPP")

ETF_All        <- lapply(ETF_Names, function(x) getSymbols(x,from="2006-01-01",auto.assign = FALSE))
names(ETF_All) <- ETF_Names

ETF_MR <- do.call(merge,lapply(ETF_All,monthlyReturn))
colnames(ETF_MR) <- ETF_Names

ETF_spec <- portfolio.spec(assets = colnames(ETF_MR))
ETF_spec <- add.constraint(portfolio=ETF_spec, type="full_investment")
ETF_spec <- add.constraint(portfolio=ETF_spec, type="box", min=0, max=1)
ETF.ef <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=ETF_MR['2015'], portfolio=ETF_spec, type="mean-StdDev")
```

Below the Error message:

```
Error in gmv_opt(R = R, constraints = constraints, moments = moments,  : 
No solution found: Error in UseMethod("as.constraint") : 
no applicable method for 'as.constraint' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'list')"
```

There have never been issues before (I just recently updated RStudio and the relevant packages). And that is when the error popped up.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.

Try adding:

```
library(ROI)
require(ROI.plugin.glpk)
require(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
```

Have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

You could try quadratic optimization (`solve.QP`). See this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30650972/2824732